# Placeholder in select type, change CSS of hidden value on select

Tags: html, css

How can I change the `"Select Month"` option to color red just like a placeholder. But the options are black. I am using the `hidden` because it is used in my javascript. I only want to change the color of the default value

```
<select class="form-control">
 <option value="" hidden="">Select Month</option>
 <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
 <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
 <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you want actively selected option to be red or just the 'Select Month' to be red?

Comment: just the 'select month' which is red but the options are black. when selecting the value in the field is black but not red.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with CSS property `color: red`, if you want to remove it when other value is selected go for the JS code below!

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.addEventListener('change', () => {
  element.classList.add("touched");
});
```

```css
select.form-control {
  color: red;
}

select.form-control.touched {
  color: black;
}

select.form-control option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="test">
  <option value="" hidden="">Select Month</option>
  <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
  <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
  <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when selected not turn to red but black. the red is just like a placeholder

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `color: red;` on *options* just like that.

The way to go about doing it is to set an `:invalid` option. And for that to work, you have to set your `<select>` as *required*.

Try this:

```css
select.form-control option{
  color: black;
}

select.form-control:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" required>
 <option value="" hidden="">Select Month</option>
 <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
 <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
 <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
</select>
```

ps: The only down side to this is that it makes this `<select>` a required feel. So if in your case, this is not a required field, then this answer is not going to work for you.

But a better solution will be to use *jQuery* and achieve this:

***Solution 2***

```js
$(".form-control").change(function(){
  var x = $( ".form-control option:selected" ).val();
  
  if(x!="") {
   $("select").css("color","black");
  } else {
   $("select").css("color","red");
  }
});
```

```css
select {
  color: red;
}

option {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control">
 <option value="" hidden="">Select Month</option>
 <option value="JAN">JAN</option>
 <option value="FEB">FEB</option>
 <option value="MAR">MAR</option>
</select>
```

In this answer, you don't need to set this as a *required* field, just the way you wanted.